# PowerShell: Automatic Join-Domain with Secure String - 'Encryption Key' Usage

Tags: script, powershell, active-directory, windows-domain

I work in an enterprise environment, where I manage a lab of 75 computers. I use Ghost to image and then I walk the computers afterwards to change the PC names and SIDs.

I am implementing a script to automatically add the computers to the domain but I am new to PowerShell and would really appreciate the help. Here's the script I'm using, 1.ps1:

```
    Param (
    [String]$User = $(Throw "MYDOMAINUSERINFO"),
     [String]$Domain = "MYDOMAININFO",
     [String]$PathToCred = "C:\OMC\AutoPost"
     ) 

    #Make sure our path string has a trailing backslash
    If ($PathToCred[$PathToCred.Length - 1] -ne "\")
    {    $PathToCred += "\"
    }

    #Now create file string
    $File = $PathToCred + "JoinDomain-$User.crd"

    #And find out if it's there, if not create it
    If (-not (Test-Path $File))
    {    (Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $File
    }

    #Load the credential file
    $Password = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($User,$Password)

    #Add the computer to the domain
    Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credential
```

I run this script using a batch file that I place in the startup folder.

```
   Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\OMC\AutoPost\1.ps1 -User MYDOMAINUSERINFO -Domain MYDOMAININFO -PathToCred C:\OMC\AutoPost\
```

Running this script works normally, it creates a credential file, reads the credential file, and joins the domain. Running this script after ghosting and walking does not work, I get the error:

```
    Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

I think this is because the computer knows that something has changed. I am using the same user account to add to the domain as I built the credentials with initially, so I believe that the computer is rejecting these credentials because the SID has changed.

I read online that I can use [-key Byte[]] to set a standard encryption key, which will allow me to get around this error. I'm too new at PowerShell to know how to use this, can anyone help me out?

```
    More info:
    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849814.aspx
    http://ss64.com/ps/convertfrom-securestring.html
```

Stack Overflow Question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258829/powershell-secure-string-encryption-key-usage-join-domain-script

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following into a script. I call mines "Custom-ZTIDomainJoin.ps1"

I place it into %SCRIPTROOT%

[CmdletBinding()]

Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        $Domain,

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    $UserName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    $Password,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    $OU,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]   
    [Switch]$Log
```

)

## Clear The Screen

```
Clear-Host
```

## Define Default Action Preferences

```
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$WarningPreference = "Continue"
```

## Define ASCII Characters

```
$Equals = [char]61
$Space = [char]32
$SingleQuote = [char]39
$DoubleQuote = [char]34
$NewLine = "`n"
```

## Set Working Directory

```
$ScriptDir =  $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition | Split-Path -Parent
$ScriptName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
$Temp = "$Env:LocalAppData\Temp"
```

## Start logging script output if the "/Log" switch is present

```
If ($Log.IsPresent) {(Start-Transcript -Path "$Temp\$ScriptName.log")}
```

## Query WMI

```
$HostName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name).Trim().ToUpper()
$OSArchitecture = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property OSArchitecture | Select -ExpandProperty OSArchitecture).Replace("-bit", "").Replace("32", "86").Insert(0,"x").ToUpper()
$OSVersion_Major = ([Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major)
$OSVersion_Minor = ([Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Minor)
[Decimal]$OSVersion = ("$OSVersion_Major" + "." + "$OSVersion_Minor")
```

## Define Functions

```
#Encode a plain text string to a Base64 string  
    Function ConvertTo-Base64 ($String) 
        { 
            $Encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($String))
            Return $Encoded  
        }   

#Decode an Base64 string to a plain text string
    Function ConvertFrom-Base64 ($String) 
        { 
            $Decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($String))
            Return $Decoded
        }
```

## If the script IS being run within a Microsoft Deployment Toolkit Task Sequence, perform the following steps

```
If (Test-Path -Path TSEnv: -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

    {           
        If ($OSVersion -lt "10.0")

            {
                #MDT passes in sensitive values as Base64 encoded strings, so they MUST be decoded to plain text first
                    $Domain = ConvertFrom-Base64 -String "$Domain"
                    $UserName = ConvertFrom-Base64 -String "$UserName"
                    $Password = ConvertFrom-Base64 -String "$Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
                    $OU = $TSEnv:MachineObjectOU

                #Create Credential Object For Active Directory Operations
                    $Credentials = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$Domain\$UserName", $Password))

                #Join the specified Active Directory Domain
                    $Device_JoinDomain = (Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials -Force -Verbose)

                #Wait 15 Seconds
                    (Start-Sleep -Seconds "15")
            }

        ElseIf ($OSVersion -ge "10.0")

            {
                #MDT passes in sensitive values as Base64 encoded strings, so they MUST be decoded to plain text first
                    $Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
                    $OU = $TSEnv:MachineObjectOU

                #Create Credential Object For Active Directory Operations
                    $Credentials = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$Domain\$UserName", $Password))

                #Join the specified Active Directory Domain
                    $Device_JoinDomain = (Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials -Force -Verbose)

                #Wait 15 Seconds
                    (Start-Sleep -Seconds "15")        
            }
   }
```

## If the script IS NOT being run within a Microsoft Deployment Toolkit Task Sequence, perform the following steps

```
ElseIf (!(Test-Path -Path TSEnv: -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))

    {
        #Convert the password to a Secure String
            $Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$Password" -AsPlainText -Force)            

        #Create Credential Object For Active Directory Operations
            $Credentials = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$Domain\$UserName", $Password))

        #Join the specified Active Directory Domain
            $Device_JoinDomain = (Add-Computer -DomainName $Domain -Credential $Credentials -Force -Verbose)

        #Wait 15 Seconds
            (Start-Sleep -Seconds "15")
    }
```

## Stop logging script output if the "/Log" switch is present

## Get-Variable | Out-GridView -Title "Variables gathered from $ScriptName.ps1" -Wait

If ($Log.IsPresent) {(Stop-Transcript)}